# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. When try to compile with Realm library 2.1.1

Tags: android, realm

I am new to realm. Tried to used with android I followed the installation step from [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation). But whenever I try to run the application it give be this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I am not sure this is a duplicate question as there are couple of other **app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac** question out there but those were not quite help full.

Comment: This sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361742/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-compilation and it's odd because this shouldn't be happening. I've been wondering if it's the `25.0.0` build tools that are causing it.

Comment: I tried with different build version too like `23.3.0`,  `24.0.0`, but no use. It still give me same error.

Comment: Did the compiler error output tell you anything specific?